# Android SQLite. No column found error

Tags: sqlite

App has no coding errors,but it crashes on launch.In the LogCat I see error no column found but I cannot figure out where is the problem. I've done a lot of research but without success so far.
Here is the source code to my classes:

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private StudentOperations studentDBoperation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    studentDBoperation = new StudentOperations(this);
    studentDBoperation.open();

    List values = studentDBoperation.getAllStudents();

    // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
    // elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addUser(View view) {

    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();

    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Student stud = studentDBoperation.addStudent(text.getText().toString(),text1.getText().toString());

    adapter.add(stud);

}

public void deleteFirstUser(View view) {

    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
    Student stud = null;

    if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
        stud = (Student) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
        studentDBoperation.deleteStudent(stud);
        adapter.remove(stud);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    studentDBoperation.open();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    studentDBoperation.close();
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Student class:

```
public class Student {

private int id;
private String name;
private String password;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

StudentOperation Class:

```
public class StudentOperations {

// Database fields
private DataBaseWrapper dbHelper;
private String[] STUDENT_TABLE_COLUMNS = { DataBaseWrapper.STUDENT_ID, DataBaseWrapper.STUDENT_NAME, DataBaseWrapper.STUDENT_PASSWORD };
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public StudentOperations(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DataBaseWrapper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public Student addStudent(String name,String password) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(DataBaseWrapper.STUDENT_NAME, name);
    values.put(DataBaseWrapper.STUDENT_PASSWORD, password);

    long studId = database.insert(DataBaseWrapper.STUDENTS, null, values);

    // now that the student is created return it ...
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseWrapper.STUDENTS,
            STUDENT_TABLE_COLUMNS, DataBaseWrapper.STUDENT_ID + " = "
                    + studId, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Student newComment = parseStudent(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newComment;
}

public void deleteStudent(Student comment) {
    long id = comment.getId();
    System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
    database.delete(DataBaseWrapper.STUDENTS, DataBaseWrapper.STUDENT_ID
            + " = " + id, null);
}

public List getAllStudents() {
    List students = new ArrayList();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseWrapper.STUDENTS,
            STUDENT_TABLE_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Student student = parseStudent(cursor);
        students.add(student);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return students;
}

private Student parseStudent(Cursor cursor) {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId((cursor.getInt(0)));
    student.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    return student;
}
```

}

DataBaseWrapper class:

```
public class DataBaseWrapper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String STUDENTS = "Students";
public static final String STUDENT_ID = "_id";
public static final String STUDENT_NAME = "name";
public static final String STUDENT_PASSWORD = "password";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Students.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// creation SQLite statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + STUDENTS
        + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + STUDENT_NAME + " text not null " + STUDENT_PASSWORD + " text not null ); ";

public DataBaseWrapper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // you should do some logging in here
    // ..

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + STUDENTS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

LogCat error:

11-05 21:51:02.430: D/AbsListView(26729): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-05 21:51:02.470: E/SQLiteLog(26729): (1) no such column: name
11-05 21:51:02.470: D/AndroidRuntime(26729): Shutting down VM
11-05 21:51:02.470: W/dalvikvm(26729): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410762a0)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlite/com.example.sqlite.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, password FROM Students
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, password FROM Students
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1012)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at com.example.sqlite.StudentOperations.getAllStudents(StudentOperations.java:62)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-05 21:51:02.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26729):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

In the DATABASE_CREATE statement, the comma between the name and password column definitions is missing.

Comment: STUDENT_NAME + " text not null ," + STUDENT_PASSWORD + " text not null

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar error when I changed(i.e. appended an additional column) in my Databasehandler file (DataBaseWrapper in your case). I found it resolved after un-installing my app from the device and then installing it again. See to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a comma to and remove a semicolon from your create statement. Try changing:

```
// creation SQLite statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + STUDENTS
    + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + STUDENT_NAME + " text not null " + STUDENT_PASSWORD + " text not null ); ";
```

to:

```
// creation SQLite statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + STUDENTS
    + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + STUDENT_NAME + " text not null, " + STUDENT_PASSWORD + " text not null )";
```